# IdeaVIM: How do I conveniently rename a variable I extract?

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

In IdeaVIM, if I extract a variable and want to name it, it seems like I'm in visual mode (the name of the variable is highlighted), yet I can't figure out a way to change what's highlighted.  Here's an image:

[image]

If I type `c`, it doesn't do anything. If I type `cc`, it changes the whole line.  Basically, it acts like I'm in command mode yet the name is highlighted as if it's in visual mode.  What I want to do 99% of the time is change this word.  Yet, the cursor is annoyingly one character after the word so `ciw` doesn't change it.

What's a convenient way to rename this variable?  I've normally done `hciw`.  I'd prefer that "extract variable" put me directly into insert mode, though.

Answer (score 6):

It's a little counterintuitive, but the easiest thing to do is just immediately hit `i` to enter insert mode, then start typing the new name, and it will replace the highlighted text.

The problem, as I see it, is that vim is modal and vanilla IntelliJ is also modal, and what you have here is the interaction of two sets of modes.  To understand the IntelliJ modes, try turning off IdeaVIM with `^Z` and use the extract variable refactoring.  Notice how if you start typing right away, what you type replaces the selected text, but if you move the cursor first and then start typing, what you type is inserted at the cursor.  Now add IdeaVIM to the mix: once you are in insert mode, IntelliJ's behavior kicks in.

See [VIM-274](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-274) for a request to change this behavior and some discussion of alternatives.

Comment: This advice works for a **rename** (and is very helpful), but it doesn't work for an "extract variable".  If I hit `i`, it doesn't do anything.  I have to press escape once or twice before it'll let me press `i`.  Try it this way: `V<extract-variable-shortcut>` if you can't reproduce.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I can reproduce when using visual mode to create the selection.  Probably worth filing in youtrack if it's not there already?  I don't see this problem because I don't normally use visual mode before "extract variable"; I use the command "extend selection" because it works on semantic units which is very convenient here.  It's bound to ⌥↑ in my keymap.

Answer (score 3):

For "Extract Variable" once you've got to the point where it's suggesting names:
[image: name suggestions]

What always works is pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>cw</kbd> and then typing the new name.
Sometimes you can press <kbd>b</kbd> right away, but often that puts me into visual mode for some reason, so pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> is guaranteed.

Comment: If you observe that pressing `Enter` doesn't work to complete the "Extract Variable" operation, then try `Escape`, `j` (down one line), and `Enter`. For some reason pressing `Enter` on a different line makes it work for me.